# How to validate that a function is executing from RAM?

Tags: ram, function

I'm trying to execute a control function as quickly as possible from SRAM on an STM32F3xx using GCC ([System Workbench toolchain](http://www.openstm32.org/Installing%2BSystem%2BWorkbench%2Bfor%2BSTM32%2Bfrom%2BEclipse)).

```
__attribute__((ramfunc)) f1(void) {
  // Set GPIO pin
  // Do something that is faster from RAM
  // Clear GPIO pin
}

void f2(void) {
  // Set GPIO pin
  // Do something that is faster from RAM
  // Clear GPIO pin
}
```

How can I check to make sure that it is actually executing from RAM?  Will printing its address tell me the flash location or the RAM location?

```
printf("f1 address = 0x%p\n", f1);
printf("f2 address = 0x%p\n", f2);
```

Is there an operation that will have an extremely different timing behavior if I measure it with an oscilloscope that I can compare?

```
f1();
f2();
```

From the `output.map` file:

```
.text.f1       0x0000000008007470       0x18 src/controller.o
.text.f2       0x0000000008007488       0x18 src/controller.o
```

From the log:

```
f1 address = 0x0x8007471
f2 address = 0x0x8007489
```

Relevant links:

http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread5894

https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/32-bit/forum.topic.html/how_can_i_executeco-6Zv7

Excerpt from `LinkerScript.ld` file showing my added `ramfunc` section that doesn't seem to be enough:

```
/* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
    *(.ramfunc)        /* .ramfunc sections */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
```

Comment: There's no need to check at runtime - your linker will put it where you told it to

Comment: ... if you suspect it did not - check the `map` file.

Comment: Yes, the address would be informative on a platform which uses physical addresses and has a known memory map.  Some processors are optimized for data access to (at least some of their) RAM and would be slower when doing memory-intensive operations while running in (that) RAM due to the necessary arbitration between instruction and data access, but that's a fairly weak way to tell.  Along those lines, some processors only support writing to flash while running from RAM.

Comment: The answer to this question probably depends very much on what architecture you are coding for and what tools (compiler & linker) you are using. Please edit to include that information in the question.

Comment: What kind of processor are we talking about here? Does it even support XIP (executing directly from flash)? It's possible that ALL code runs from RAM, especially given that both functions have addresses that appear to be in the same space.

Comment: The addresses in question make this look like a classic ARM Cortex M part.  These are *built* to execute from flash (both addresses would be in flash on such a part), but they *can* execute from RAM, sometimes a little more slowly.  Look at the first word of your binary (or the linker script where it comes from) and you'll see an address in RAM that initializes the stack pointer, probably at the top of RAM actually...  So it seems you have not succeeded in putting this routine in RAM yet.

Comment: RAM on your STM32F3 starts at 0x20000000...   You may not have the ramfunc stuff setup correctly in your linker script yet or it may have a different name there.  You should edit the relevant portion of your linker script file (typically .ld) into your question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  "sometimes a little more slowly"  Are you sure?  I mean -- I've never tested it, but at least on one of the parts I've worked with you need lots of wait states on flash memory if it's running flat out, but none on RAM.

Comment: For example, some L073 HAL code I have handy at the moment says `GNU Compiler RAM functions are defined using a specific toolchain attribute
         "__attribute__((section(".RamFunc")))".`

Comment: It's an ARM Cortex-M processor, so use the debugger and trace your instruction execution.

Comment: @TimWescott interesting point. I'd been thinking about the dedicated optimal data paths of the "Harvard-ish" architecture but not the underlying memory technology.  Would be interesting to find out the end result both for something register based and something that needs a lot of data access to RAM at the same time, you could well be right...

Answer (score 3):

Wow, OK, thanks for clarifying where RAM starts on this device, Chris Stratton.

It looks like I finally proved that it can work on a more isolated project.

Control experiment:

```
f1 address = 0x0x8003161
f2 address = 0x0x8003179
```

After qualifying the function signature:

```
__attribute__ ((section (".ramfunc"))) void f1(void) {
...
}
```

I get log line:

```
f1 address = 0x0x200009b9
f2 address = 0x0x8003161
```

Note that this required adding the `.ramfunc` line to the linker script:

```
/* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
    *(.ramfunc)        /* .ramfunc sections */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
```

To directly answer the original question, yes, you should be able to print the address of the function and see that it is in a different region OR check the .map file OR use the debugger to check this address.

Comment: Glad it worked, good writeup!